# Is it posible to pick a date or put text on one input and automatic should apear on other one too

Tags: javascript, php, html

**This is my form1**

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="#">
<input id="date_input_2" type="text" name="emp_item_hawala_date" />
<input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

**this is my form2 which I want its text input to just get automatic from form1 when ever I enter text to input (emp_item_hawala_date) from form1 the same input of form2 should take it's text too.**

```
<form name="form2" method="post" action="#">
<input id="date_input_1" type="text" name="emp_item_hawala_date" />
<input type="submit" value="print">
</form>
```

Here on my form1 I want to put by selectively or input direct it should apear on my second form input by automatic.

is it possible?

regards

Comment: Are they in the same file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the form1, do following:

```
<input id="date_input_2" type="text" name="emp_item_hawala_date" onblur=(document.getElementById('date_input_1').value=this.value) />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simple use key up function.

u add datepicker in it..

http://jsfiddle.net/DfHSS/

```
   $("#date_input_1").keyup(function(){
       $("#date_input_2").val($(this).val());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this jquery code

```
<script>
$("document").ready(function(){

$("#date_input_1").keyup(function(){
$("#date_input_2").val($(this).val());
});
$("#date_input_2").keyup(function(){
$("#date_input_1").val($(this).val());
});


});


</script>
```